# How to use Shrinker (R8) with react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm updating react-native version to 0.60.4, but when i try to build release i got stuck in Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease

I've tried to disable R8 and works but got a 3 times bigger apk

```
R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.
Current version is: 1.4.94 (build 3904928f0db9c3bf128ce3bbfb160 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-5g74)).


D8: The rule `-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule {
  *;
}` uses extends but actually matches implements.
D8: The rule `-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule {
  *;
}` uses extends but actually matches implements.
D8: The rule `-keep public class * extends androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable {
  <init>();
}` uses extends but actually matches implements.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link which has the answer to your question.

[android studio 3.5 Warning: The rule `-keep public class * extends androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable { <init>(); }` uses extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601897/android-studio-3-5-warning-the-rule-keep-public-class-extends-androidx-vers)